# Sum and Running Sum, Distinct and Running Distinct

Tags: sql

I want to calculate sum, running sum, distinct, running distinct - preferably all in one query.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/65eff/1

```
create table test (store int, day varchar(10), food varchar(10), quantity int)
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'rice', 1
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'rice', 1
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'rice', 2
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'fruit', 2
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'water', 3
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'fruit', 1
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-01', 'salt', 2
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-02', 'rice', 1
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-02', 'rice', 2
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-02', 'fruit', 1
insert into test select 101, '2021-01-02', 'pepper', 4
```

Uniques (distinct) & Total (sum) are simple:

```
select store, day, count(distinct food) as uniques, sum(quantity) as total
from test
group by store, day
```

But I want output to be :

| store | day | uniques | run_uniques | total | run_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-01-01 | 4 | 4 | 12 | 12 |
| 101 | 2021-01-02 | 3 | 5 | 10 | 22 |

I tried a self-join with t.day >= prev.day to get cumulative/running data, but it's causing double-counting.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting RDBMS tags... please add back the single tag of relevance.

Comment: @DaleK - any ANSI query, or any RDBMS works for me. I can translate to others if needed. also, many queries do not conflict across db's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: **always** store data in the correct data type, `day` should be a `date` column.

**Calculating a running sum of `sum(quantity)` aggregate is quite simple**, you just nest it inside a window function: `SUM(SUM(...)) OVER (...)`.

Calculating the running number of unique `food` per `store` is more complicated because you want the rolling number of unique items *before* grouping, and there is no `COUNT(DISTINCT` window function in SQL Server (which is what I'm using).

So I've gone with calculating a `row_number()` for each `store` and `food` across all days, then we just sum up the number of times we get `1` i.e. this is the first time we've seen this `food`.

```sql
SELECT
    t.store,
    t.day,
    uniques =     COUNT(DISTINCT t.food),
    run_uniques = SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
                    OVER (PARTITION BY t.store ORDER BY t.day ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),
    total =       SUM(t.quantity),
    run_total =   SUM(SUM(t.quantity))
                    OVER (PARTITION BY t.store ORDER BY t.day ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store, food ORDER BY day) rn
    FROM test
) t
GROUP BY t.store, t.day;
```

Comment: Brilliant ! Works on SQL & Presto. FYI, it does not run in Hive QL - *"Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. Invalid column reference 'rownum'"*